# Cancel or Stop an Azure Function Instance

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-server

In my Azure function, I am executing a stored procedure. Now, based on some event, I want to cancel the execution of this particular instance. Sample code below (very simplified for example purpose):-

```
public async Task AddTestMessage(string name, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
             using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("uspTest", connection))
             {
                   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                   SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[]
                   {
                       new SqlParameter("name", name),
                   };
                   command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
                   token.Register(() => command.Cancel());
                   connection.Open();
                   command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
              }
         }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Cancellation Requested: {ex.Message}");

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }      
}
```

Now, in any other application it's very easy to set the `CancellationTokenSource` passed to this method, but in Azure functions since we can't have multiple trigger, I can think of no way if it's possible to cancel the SQL Server stored procedure.

I know it's possible with a durable function but just want to know if there is any way to achieve this using normal function?

Comment: Why are you wrapping a library that has native `async`-friendly methods in `Task.Run`?

Comment: @DanielMann - Sure it's not needed, I can simply do `ExecuteNonQueryAsync`. It was just a test code from other app, my question is just about `CancellationToken` and if it can be set in some way.

Comment: This is a good example of where serverless falls down, in my opinion. Typically you could set up a pub/sub subscriber and then cancel the token if it matches, but then you violate the nature of the Function app in the first place.

Comment: @DavidL - Thank you! Could you please elaborate on this approach?