# Service Bus Processor Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function in which I am using the Service bus processor to receieve message from Service bus Topic while the function is running (Please note this is not the trigger).
Based on the message receieved from the Topic, I am setting a CancellationToken.

I was able to move all the service bus related code in a separate service and injecting the `ServiceBusClient` in Program.cs:-

```
 builder.Services.AddAzureClients(clientBuilder =>
 {
     clientBuilder.AddServiceBusClientWithNamespace(serviceBusOptions.ServiceBusUri)
                  .WithCredential(new DefaultAzureCredential())
                  .ConfigureOptions(options =>
                   {
                          //
                   });
 }
```

But I am not sure if I can also inject the [Service Bus Processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions?tabs=passwordless) or if I can move this logic to a service. Based on the [docmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions?tabs=passwordless), it's recommended to be cached.

Current code (Inside function):-

```
 processor = queueService.GetProcessor(subscriptionName);
 processor.ProcessMessageAsync += async (ProcessSessionMessageEventArgs args) => {...} 
 processor.ProcessErrorAsync += Processor_ProcessErrorAsync;
 await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
```

I want to avoid keeping this code inside the main function class, is there any way to inject it or better write the same?

**Edit:** The function runs some sql stored procedures, at time the procedure might take time and user may request cancellation. Since there is no other way to stop the running instance of function, I went with this approach. Please suggest if there is any better way to stop a running function instance.

Comment: This is the wrong way to solve the problem you're facing. An azure function, in a way **is** a processor. Perhaps you should first explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @SeanFeldman - Thanks, added why I am using SB here. I had asked on cancellation on MS Q&A[1]

Comment: I still don't understand why you need a `ServiceBusProcessor`. What's the relationship between the Function and the SQL SPROC. What are you trying to achieve here? What type of trigger are you using? Like I said, a function _is_ a processor on its own. It feels like something is off here.

Comment: I am curious, how does the  `ProcessMessageAsync` implementation looks like, how does it cancel the query?

Comment: @SeanFeldman@Peter - Please check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718728/cancel-or-stop-an-azure-function-instance , the function itself is triggered by service bus queue but since there is no way to cancel a running instance of function I tried this approach. If you are wondering why I am trying to cancel the SP, unfortunately our business requirement is stop any backend sql immediately when user request to cancel the request.

Comment: +1 to Sean's statement.  I agree that an Azure Function is likely not the best approach to meet those requirements.  Creating your own BackgroundService-based implementation where you own the processor instance and can manage it's operation and lifetime would seem to fit your needs better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as someone pointed out already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72718728/cancel-or-stop-an-azure-function-instance#comment128447927_72718728), I have a similar feeling about this approach.

The issue is with running a `ServiceBusProcessor` within a function. While technically it's possible, it's not designed for a short term execution. `ServiceBusProcessor` in it's own is a message pump. So is Azure function. Perhaps function based implementation is not the approach for this scenario.

Comment: I agree and I was hestitant to do this too but it's part of a large app already running in Prod and now I need to implement cancellation.  If for the time-being I go with this approach where would you suggest keeping the `StartProcessingAsync` to start the processor?

Comment: You're forcing me to take a shower, aren't ya?  A function is a process. While your function (method) is alive, you're free to do what you want. So you could run a task and have that task tight to a cancellation process. The task would be starting the processor and do it's work. But it feels so hacky...